# What are the dangers of using InfluxDB with networked storage (SSD) instead of local disks for production?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, influxdb, persistent-storage

We are thinking of running InfluxDB inside Kubernetes (on GKE) and using Google's networked storage [Persistent Disk SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk/) for our production database.

Has anyone done this before? [InfluxDB's documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/guides/hardware_sizing/) says that it's not tested against networked storage devices.

If all the other sizing and performance numbers are within InfluxDB's recommendation, what are the foreseeable issues that could occur with running a database on Kubernetes with networked storage?